# How to split a file based on a list of patterns and name the output files asthe pattern?

Tags: text-processing, files, grep, split

File1 looks like this (metabolic pathway:gene):

A:1 
A:2 
A:3 
B:a 
B:b 
C:pp 
D:rr

How to obtain an output file that looks like this (named as File1.new):

A:1, 2, 3
B:a, b
C:pp
D:rr

I am a Linux beginner. Easy explanations are preferable!

Comment: What is file2 used for? Does the output look different depending on what it contains?

Comment: @RalphRönnquist Actually, it doesnt. No, it doesnt. If there is a way to get File3 from File1, that'll be all I'll need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```
datamash -t: groupby 1 collapse 2 < file
A:1,2,3
B:a,b
C:pp
D:rr
```

If you want the counts as well,

```
datamash -t: groupby 1 collapse 2 count 2 < file
A:1,2,3:3
B:a,b:2
C:pp:1
D:rr:1
```

You can also `countunique` if you want the number of unique fields.

Answer (score 3):

this is a job for awk.

```
awk -F: '{L[$1]=L[$1] "," $2} 
    END { for (l in L) printf "%s:%s\n",l,substr(L[l],2);}'
```

where

- `-F:` use `:` as separator
- `{L[$1]=L[$1] "," $2}` store comma separated value indexed by field 1
- `END` at end of file
- `for (l in L)`  loop through values
- `printf "%s:%s\n",l,substr(L[l],2);` print, skipping first comma
- you may use `","` or `", "`, adjust final substr accordingly.

awk can be one-lined, use

```
awk -F: '....' File1 > File3
```

to count gene simply add a var tou count (here G).

```
{L[$1]=L[$1] "," $2;G[$1]++} 
END { for (l in L) printf "%s:%s:%d\n",l,substr(L[l],2),G[l];}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Also, is there a way to count the number of genes (i.e. the characters following ':' in File3) and print it at the end of the corresponding line?

Answer (score 0):

## Data Structure

```
 %h = (
     ...
      B => [a, b],
      A => [1, 2, 3],
     ...
 );


perl -F':' -lane '
   push @{$h{$F[0]}}, $F[1]}{
   $"=",";
   print "$_:", "@{$h{$_}}|", scalar @{$h{$_}} for keys %h;
' File1 > File1.new
```

## Brief

```
The field separator is set to a semicolon, thus populating each time a line is read in afresh 
the @F array. Then we append the 2nd field, $F[1], to the array of hash
keyed in on the 1st field, $F[0]. At the end, we display the key name,
followed by the array contents corresponding to this key, & the count of
the array as well.
```

## Output

```
A:1,2,3|3
B:a,b|2
C:pp|1
D:rr|1
```

## Sed

```
sed -e '
  :loop
     $!N
     s/^\(\([^:]*\):.*\)\n\2:\(.*\)/\1,\3/
   tloop
   P;D
' yourfile
```